# Cant find Firebase Assistant in Android Studio 3.3

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-assistant

I just updated Android Studio to version 3.3 and I'm looking to create a new Firebase application using the Firebase Assistant. But I dont see it under tools.

I checked which plugins I have installed and I have all three firebase plugins.

I checked which Google Repository I have under SDK Manager, and I'm on 58

When I do a search of Android Studio I can find it but when I press enter I get this error:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIndexedListIterator.next(AbstractIndexedListIterator.java:75)
    at com.google.services.firebase.DependencyStateManager.getDependencyState(DependencyStateManager.java:59)
    at com.google.services.firebase.DependencyStateManager.init(DependencyStateManager.java:108)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.view.StatefulButton.<init>(StatefulButton.java:98)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.view.TutorialStep.<init>(TutorialStep.java:114)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.view.TutorialCard.redraw(TutorialCard.java:161)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.view.TutorialCard.<init>(TutorialCard.java:94)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.view.FeaturesPanel.<init>(FeaturesPanel.java:84)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.AssistSidePanel.<init>(AssistSidePanel.kt:79)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.AssistToolWindowFactory.createToolWindowContent(AssistToolWindowFactory.java:44)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.OpenAssistSidePanelAction.openWindowNow(OpenAssistSidePanelAction.java:68)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.OpenAssistSidePanelAction.lambda$openWindow$0(OpenAssistSidePanelAction.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:315)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.doRun(LaterInvocator.java:447)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:431)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:415)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:817)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:758)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:394)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: I've also tried to manually add Firebase to my project using [these instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?authuser=0#manually_add_firebase) but I get an error on the first step: `There was an unknown error while processing the request. Try again.`